# Adding Cookies to API

Tags: javascript, html

I'm making a neat little Fortnite stats website using FortniteTracker.com's API, but I want to add cookies to the website so that I don't need to continuously type in the same name over and over again. Is there a simple few lines of code I can add to my input method of

```
<input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Username" id="username">
```

If this is too vague I sincerely apologize. I'm only about two months into coding, and this is only my second question

Comment: It's not quite clear what you are trying to achieve. If it's to "remember" values the user previously typed in, yes you can do it with cookies - but you'll probably find using local storage easier. It's also not clear what you want to do if, for example, the user types in several usernames in succession - which, if any, should be saved?

Comment: @RobinZigmond I'm trying to remember the values the user typed in. I would prefer that only valid usernames be remembered, but if that's too difficult then I'm still happy with all usernames being saved

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You will need a function that handles when you submit the form. If you are using vanilla JS this can be done with onsubmit, [here is an explanation of it](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/event_onsubmit.asp) .

To create this function that adds the cookies, [here is a really good explanation of how to do it](https://www.the-art-of-web.com/javascript/setcookie/) .

My answer is probably a bit vague but following these will really help. Let me know if you have any problems